# Preview code in IDE

Tags: netbeans, ide

I usualy use Netbeans. But n.b. don't have preview code window like this screen.
(Right part of screen - mini-column) Plugins disabled for this theme.

I want those window!

Thank you all.

[image]

Comment: If you want that, you want Sublime Text.  I'm not sure what value you see in it...it's infinitely small text that, if I *really* wanted to know what it was, I'd have to scroll to or find a method/keyword anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netbeans has this feature now. E.g. Netbeans 8.2 `View -> Show Outline` will give you this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is [an open bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=199663) in Netbeans issue manager, therefore I think there is no such option.

You can register and vote for it but I wouldn't expect this anytime soon.